# Array value operators

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the select field below only to show only when the value of the platform field is 4 or greater. Is it possible to nest an operator within the array statement? The code below works if I change `>=` to `=> 4` however that only works when the platform value is 4 and I need to to be any time it's 4 or greater.

```
$form['model'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Select a Model'),
  '#options' => array(0 => t('- Select -')) + $options,
  '#default_value' => 0,
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(':input[name=platform]' => array('value' >= 4)),
    'required' => array(':input[name=platform]' => array('value' >= 4)),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array('value' >= 4)` is not the correct syntax to define an array containing the index `value`.

Basing on [Fixed conditionals to allow OR and XOR constructions](http://drupal.org/node/1464758), you can use the following code.

```
$form['model'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Select a Model'),
  '#options' => array(0 => t('- Select -')) + $options,
  '#default_value' => 0,
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      array(
        array(':input[name=platform]' => array('value' => 4)),
        array(':input[name=platform]' => array('value' => 5)),
        array(':input[name=platform]' => array('value' => 6)),
        array(':input[name=platform]' => array('value' => 7)),
      ),
    ),
    'required' => array(
      array(
        array(':input[name=platform]' => array('value' => 4)),
        array(':input[name=platform]' => array('value' => 5)),
        array(':input[name=platform]' => array('value' => 6)),
        array(':input[name=platform]' => array('value' => 7)),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Using this code, the form field will be visible when the other form field value is one of the following values: 4, 5, 6, 7. It works with Drupal 7.14, or higher.